# Is there a simpler way of solving this algebra problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is motivated by the television show Jeopardy. In the final round of the show, each player can wager any amount up to their current winnings. The wager amount is added to or subtracted from their current winnings, depending on whether they guess the answer to the final question.

Suppose that there are two players remaining in the final round and the person in second place has 8,000 dollars.   Obviously, if the person in first place has over 16,000 dollars, they can guarantee victory by not wagering anything.

Suppose we eliminate the possibility that the person in first guesses the last question incorrectly and the other person gets it right.  What is the least amount that the person in first needs to assure victory?

This is what I came up with.
We only need to consider the cases where both players guess correctly or both guess incorrectly.
Let m be the current amount that the player has and b be the amount of the bet.  m + b > 16,000. m-b > 8000. Adding the two inequalities gives 2m > 24000 or m > 12000.

Surely there is a more straightforward way of solving this.  Intuitively, 12000 can be thought of as splitting the difference between 8000 and 16000, so having 12000 and betting 4000 would move the player to either 16000 or 8000.

---

I found this intuitive approach:

Start by considering the case where the leader has 8001.  Then if they both answer incorrectly, the leader wins by not wagering anything. If they both answer correctly then the leader ends up with 8001 compared to the opponent's $16000.

Now suppose the leader has an additional 10, so they start with $8011. Betting $10 again gives the leader $8001 if both guess incorrectly.  The leader ends up with 8011 + 10 = 8021 if they both answer correctly.

The thing to notice is that, in general, giving the leader an extra x will have them ending up with an additional 2x.  To get to $16001, the leader needs to end up with an additional 8000, and so needs to start with an additional 4000.

Therefore the solution is that to guarantee victory for the two cases, the leader needs to start with 8001 + 4000 = 12001 and should bet $4000. In general, if the opponent has N then the leader needs 3/2 N  to guarantee winning.

Comment: I do not know the rules of Jeopardy for sure , but if I remember right one must wager at least $1$ dollar. The exercise is pretty easy : Double the amount the enemy has and wager such that you have still more than this amount in the case you answer wrong. If the amounts are $a$ and $b$ with $2a<b$ , $b$ can wager upto $b-2a-1$ dollars and will stin win for sure.

Comment: The J! Archive has a wagering calculator to explore many scenarios. Looks like you've described the one-half for first situation. See here: https://www.j-archive.com/wageringcalculator.php

Answer (score 3):

Say the leading player has $M$ and the runner up has $N$.

There are two bad scenarios you are willing to consider:  Both get it right but the lead player didn't bet enough, and Both get it wrong and the lead player bet too much.  Clearly, these are at odds with each other.

For the first scenario (both right): the lead player needs to beat $2N$ to ensure victory.  Thus they need to bet $2N-M+1$.  You can skip the extra dollar if ties are tolerable (after all, the lead player really only cares about making sure they advance...strictly beating the other player isn't an obvious priority).

Now, assume the lead player has bet $2N-M+1$.  Can they survive the second bad scenario (both wrong)?

Now we must assume that the runner up, perhaps anticipating this scenario, bets nothing.  Thus, to survive this, we must require that $M-(2N-M+1)>N$

That's the same as $$M-2N+M-1>N\iff 2M-1>3N\iff M>\frac {3N+1}2$$

Of course, if ties are tolerable, you can just drop that additive $1$ throughout.

Thus, the lead player needs about $150\%$ of the runner ups total to ensure victory in these two scenarios.

Comment: Ties aren't allowed in regular play anymore; if a tie occurs after FJ! then there is a sudden death clue.

Comment: @SeanRoberson  Ah, thanks!  Haven't watched in years...guess they changed the rules.

Comment: Yes - as of November 2014. Ties were always broken in tournament play. See here: https://www.j-archive.com/help.php#tiebreakerround

Comment: I found a slightly different way of expressing this, which is easier for me to follow.  Let N=amount other person has,  N+x the amount that leader has and b=size of bet.  For the case where both players win, then N+x+b=2N.  b = N-x. For when they both lose, we must have N+x-b > N.  Substituting for b, we get N+x-(N-x) > N.  2x > N.   x > N/2.  The person started with N+x > 3N/2

Comment: I updated the original question to give an intuitive mostly  non-algebraic solution to the problem, and included this solution in a separate answer document.

Answer (score 0):

I found this intuitive approach:

Start by considering the case where the leader has 8001.Then if
they both answer incorrectly,the leader wins by not wagering anything.If they both answer  correctly then the leader ends up with
8001 compared to the opponent's 16000.

Now suppose the leader has an additional 10 and bets 10,so they start with 8001 + 10 = 8011. Betting 10 again gives the leader
8001 if both guess incorrectly, so 10 is the largest possible bet. The leader ends up with 8011 + 10 = 8021 if they both answer correctly.

The thing to notice is that, in general, giving the leader 8001 + x and betting x will have them ending up with 8001 for the case where they both answer incorrectly and 8001 + 2x for when they both answer correctly. To get from 8001 to 16001 for the second case,the leader needs to end up with an additional 8000, and so needs to start with an additional 4000 and bet 4000.

Therefore the solution is that to guarantee victory for the two cases, the leader needs to start with 8001 + 4000 = 12001 and should bet
4000. Starting with an amount greater than 12001 and betting 4000 will give final amounts greater than 8001 and 16001 for the two cases. In general, if the opponent has N then for the case where they are both correct the leader needs an additional 2N+1 - (N+1) = N and so must start out with an amount greater than or equal to N+1 + N/2 =  3/2 N + 1 to guarantee winning.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the amount that the second place player has, as a portion of the first place player's amount (that is, $p$ = (second place amount)/(first place amount)). The second place player could wager nothing and end up with $p$ even if they give an incorrect response, so the first place player can't wager more than $1-p$ (if the first place player wagers $1-p$ and loses, then they end up with $1-(1-p)=p$). This means that if the give the correct response, they will have less than $1+(1-p) = 2-p$. The second place player, however, could wager all of their money, and then if they give the correct response, they will end up with $2p$. So the critical amount is when $2-p = 2p$. Solving for $p$, we get $3p = 2$, or $p =2/3$.

So, if the second place player has less than 66% of the first place amount, then the first place player can wager 33% of their own amount. If they get the response correct, they end up with 133% of their original amount, which is more than the second place amount doubled. If they give the incorrect response, they end up with 66%, which is more than the second place player will have if they also are incorrect.

> depending on whether they guess the answer to the final question.

Incorrect. They are asked to give the QUESTION for the final ANSWER.