# Can inequalities be added the way that equations can be added?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, if you have $x > 6$ and $y > 4$, then obviously $x + y > 10$.  If you have $x > 6$ and $y < 4$, then the second inequality can be changed to $-y > -4$. Now adding $x > 6$ gives $x-y > 2$, which is obviously true.  Now suppose you have $x + y > 6$ and $x - y > 4$. Adding the inequalities, the $y$ terms cancel and you end up with $2x > 10$ or $x > 5$. It is not intuitively obvious to me that this holds true, but I could not come up with a counter-example. I can see that you can't subtract inequalities, but is it always okay to add them?

Comment: You do what you can logically justify. Mathematics is not about mysterious rules; everything you teacher told you is "ok" can be justified (hopefully...). $2x=x+y+x-y>6+x-y>6+4=10$, so, yes

Comment: If they go the same way, you can add them.  If they go opposite ways and you add them, there will be a fight and the strongest direction will win.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Related: [When can you subtract two inequalities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4274932/25554)

Answer (score 4):

Consider any two inequalities $a < b$ and $c < d$, where each of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ is real. Since $a < b$, it must be the case that (colloquially speaking) shifting each of them the same distance up or down the real line won’t disrupt things. In other words, $a + c < b + c$. (Note that this last bit wasn’t a proof, but merely an attempt to help you hone your intuition.)

But by the exact same kind of reasoning, it follows from  $c < d$ that $b + c < b + d$. And now, all we need is the transitivity of *less-than*: Since

$$a + c < b + c < b + d,$$

we conclude that $a + c < b + d$.

Comment: Looks like we were typing the same thing at the same time, down to the choice of variables! Great minds think alike. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you know that you can add the same thing to both sides of an inequality, no? That is, if you know that
$$ x \lt y$$ then
$$ x +z \lt y+z$$
is valid.

Now, your question is: If I know that $$a \lt b$$ and $$c \lt d$$
does this imply that $$ a+c \lt b+d \text{  ?}$$

It does, and here's how to prove it. Add $c$ to both sides of your first inequality to get $$a+c \lt b+c$$
and then add $b$ to both sides of your second inequality to get
$$ b+c \lt b+d$$
and then just use transitivity ($r \lt s$ and $s \lt t$ imply $r \lt t$) on those last two inequalities to get the inequality you wanted.

Comment: Then it is perfectly okay to add inequalities.  In particular, the original solution I gave in this question is perfectly reasonable, though maybe not intuitively obvious. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729228/is-there-a-simpler-way-of-solving-this-algebra-problem

I was also thinking that you could go from equations to inequalities by saying that x > y is equivalent to saying that x = y + p for some positive number p.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have two bags of cookies, $a$ and $b$. A friendly baker comes by and offers to trade with you: you will give the baker your bag $a$ and in return you will get a larger bag $c$ which contains **more cookies**. That is, $a<c$. You like cookies, so you agree.

Now the friendly baker offers the same deal for bag $b$: you will give up $b$ and in  return you get a bigger bag $d$ that again contains **more cookies**. That is, $c<d$. You make that trade and the baker leaves.

Later you open the bags and count up your cookies. You have $c+d$ now, and you had $a+b$ before. Is it possible that you might not have more cookies than before you made the trades?

No, it's obviously impossible.

But that's what it would mean if $a<c$ and $b<d$ but not  $a+b<c+d$ too.  So that is also impossble.